# Get Process ID of COM Server

Tags: winapi, com, moniker, com-server

I'm doing some automation via a combination of windows message sending directly to HWNDs and calls to a COM server exposed by the automated application.

If there is more than one instance running, I need to be able to determine the process ID of the COM server so I can hit the same instance with the COM call as the one I'm sending windows messages to.

I can enumerate all the running COM servers with the running object table and get back monikers for all of them, but the COM objects themselves expose no methods I can use to get a window handle, thread ID, process ID, or anything of that sort.

Is there any way to figure out, based on a moniker or the actual binding COM object of the moniker, what the process ID of the COM server is?

Thanks!

Comment: No, making this info undiscoverable is very much by design.  You need help from the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you control (write code for) both the server and the client you can add a method to your COM interface that would return the process / thread ID or anything of this nature (e.g. server hostname if it is remote) on the server end. I second @Hans - unless you have access to the server implementation you may be out of luck by design.

Comment: This isn't really really an attractive solution, since the server could then potentially lie about its PID.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the kimgr [CoGetServerPID](https://github.com/kimgr/cogetserverpid) function will give you the process-id of your COM server. However, it only works if the process-id is <65k.

You can also use [GetWindowThreadProcessId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid)  if you already have the window handle (HWND).

There's also a [3 Ways to Get a COM Server Process ID](https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/724-windows-three-ways-to-get-com-server-process-id) blog post that might be worth taking a look at. Haven't tried it myself though.