# How do I get process that was launched as server-in-exe by client call?

Tags: com, system, com-interop

I have client code like that:

```
Dim server as Object
Set server = CreateObject("some-prog-id")
```

Server-in-exe is launched and for some reasons it hangs from time to time. I have to kill it in taskmanager to make my client alive. 
I'd like to kill Sever-in-exe process automatically when time is expired but don't know how to properly get it's ID. Actually I know process name but there could be several processes with the same name that were launched previously.

How do I determine process that was launched by my client code?

Comment: Short answer is you can't. Is it a custom made out-of-process server or dllhost.exe, or else? If it's custom, you could add a "get process id"-like interface.

Comment: @SimonMourier, if I understand you correctly you advise to extend server interface with method that would return it's process id. Sorry, it's impossible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Process ID of COM Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046433/get-process-id-of-com-server)